# No UEFI Settings option in Win 10

Tags: windows-10

I have Lenovo ThinkCentre MT-M10AU, upgraded to Win 10. I have created a recovery DVD but can't boot from it. In Win 10 Settings>blah>blah I don't get a UEFI settings option presented anywhere. How can I get into the bios to change the boot order?

Comment: Try pushing F1 as soon as it boots.

Comment: Boot into Windows, use the Advanced Startup, in order to access your firmware settings.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solved this myself. The only way (indirectly) into the bios was by using F12 at a cold start-up. F2 did not work and the bios was completely inaccessible from Windows 10.

Thanks to anyone who expended a brain cell on this.